# how can I send cc mail in python using smtplib

Tags: python-3.x, smtplib, cc

with my current code, I am able to send bcc but I want to send cc how can I do so.

I tried splitting the mail using [string.split(",")].Though It said it could not process lists.
Since I am a beginner python programmer that is the maximum I could do.

'''python
import smtplib

to_send = input("who to send")
class mail:

```
def send_bcc(which_mail_service,your_mailing_address,password,subject,body):
    try:
                    with smtplib.SMTP(f"smtp.{which_mail_service}.com", 587) as smtp:
                        smtp.ehlo()
                        smtp.starttls()
                        smtp.ehlo()
                        smtp.login(your_mailing_address,password)
                        msg = ("Subject:" + subject + "\n\n" + body)
                        smtp.sendmail(your_mailing_address, to_send, msg)
                        smtp.quit()
                    print("Your mail sent.")

    except KeyError:
        print("The Email not found.")
mail.send_bcc("gmail", "rajdipshah6@gmail.com", "face book", to_send[0], "bla")
```

mail.send_bcc("gmail", "rajdipshah6@gmail.com", "face book", to_send[0], "bla","bbla")
'''

How can I send cc [ multiple mails at once ]